# Easily Zoom an Image in Silverlight 3 with slider control

Tags: silverlight, zooming

Simple question,

SilverLight 3 application (no toolkit).
I want to use an image and a slider.
The image is displayed fit to screen on load, and then the slider has to zoom-in and out the image when its value changes. I don't want to use anything else, like deepzoom. How can this be done?

Urgent, Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xaml code below :

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scroll"   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
<layout:LayoutTransformer x:Name="layout"  Background="{x:Null}" >
                                <layout:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="contentScale" ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0" />
                                </layout:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>

                                <Image x:Name="img"   Source="../pin.PNG"  >

                                </Image>
                            </layout:LayoutTransformer>
                        </ScrollViewer>
```

And on the slidervaluechangedevent :

```
    this.contentScale.ScaleX = this.contentScale.ScaleY = e.NewValue;
    this.layout.ApplyLayoutTransform();
```

LayoutTransformer is ther in toolkit, add its reference:

```
System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit
```

Without having a toolkit, u can  do it but it doesn't work properly(it will never update the scrollviewer)...try it the below one :

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scroll"   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Themes:ThemeManager.StyleKey="TreeScrollViewer">

                                <Image x:Name="img"   Source="../charge_chargeline.PNG"  >
                                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="contentScale" ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0" />
                                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                                </Image>

                        </ScrollViewer>
```

And on the slidervaluechangedevent :

```
    `this.contentScale.ScaleX = this.contentScale.ScaleY = e.NewValue`;
```

Hope it helps :)....

Comment: Can;t find the LayoutTransformer, do i need to download the SilverLight toolkit?
Please elaborate

Comment: Thanks Malcom, Does installing the toolkit on the developer machine require any additional installation or modification on the production machine where the silverlight app will be finally installed?

Comment: I hope when silverlight app will be installed it will also store the dlls in some lib folder or some other, so put this dll in your globel lib (where u will be putting other dlls required).
Because the final point is you must have that dll physically stored in u r app.(Then it doesn't matters whether its on production machine or developers machine or any other machine)